# C/C++ overwriting function argument that is a text pointer

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I found this construct which I'm not sure if it's valid.

```
#include <iostream>
#define DEFAULT_TEXT "hello world"

void print_text(const char* custom_text) {

    if(!custom_text) {
        custom_text = DEFAULT_TEXT;
    }

    std::cout << custom_text << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    print_text(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without error and its output is "hello world" as expected.

The function argument is a variable containing a pointer. By calling the function it contains a nullptr. Within the function the argument variable is overwritten with a pointer to the default text "hello world". That is defined by a preprocessor macro and expanded within an if statement that has limited scope within the if block.

Is this a valid stable construct? What's about the terminating null character of "hello world"? Have I to add one?

Comment: IMHO, not a valid **stable** construct.  Use `std::string`  pass by reference if the parameter is modified by the function or `const` reference if the function does not modify the parameter. If you use `std::string`, the terminating nul character is not needed.

Comment: C string literals represent null-terminated arrays.  No need to add an extra nul byte, nor to be concerned that one might be missing.  Or on the other hand, yes, the nul-termination is needed for printing it via `cout.<<`.

Comment: You don't need the `;` in the macro definition. It happens not to cause problems the way you use it, but it could cause syntax errors or worse.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid stable construct.  The terminating null character which the compiler generates is needed.  (I don't know how you'd suppress it.)  The final `;` in the `#define` should not be there.  No reason to use `std::endl`, avoid the extra work the stream is doing by using `"\n"` instead.  I recommend avoiding macros if possible, and it is possible in this case.

Comment: @Eljay stable or not stable and needed null character or not, that's the question. What comment is right?

Comment: It is stable.  `"hello world"` has an implicit null character.  The implicit null character is needed.

Comment: @Eljay OK, I meant "Have I to add a null char?", will improve the question.

Comment: @Ingo [This is where it is not stable](https://godbolt.org/z/bKa9hcaPd).  If the text is not null terminated, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you mean by "stable".

Comment: OP asked "an if statement that has limited scope within the if block", I think he's worried that the pointer could dangle.  If it were pointing to a temporary object, that would be a problem, but string literals have unlimited lifetime, they don't die and a pointer to a string literal will continue working.

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct, I fear a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Ingo: A pointer to a string literal stays valid "forever" (until your program exits)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is a modern alternative, as there are no ownership  (or old C-API) involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's valid (though not great style in some ways).

`custom_text` is a parameter, which makes it a *local variable* inside the function `print_text()`. A parameter is initialized with the value of the corresponding argument in the call (`nullptr` in this case).

A function is free to change the values of any of its local variables.

A C-style string includes a terminating null character `'\0'`. You don't need to worry about it, since it's implicit in the string literal `"hello world"`.

It would probably be better style to use `std::string` rather than raw C-style strings, but C++ deals with C-style strings without too many problems.

You could also define your function with a default parameter value rather than writing that logic in the body of the function.

One thing you should change is to delete the semicolon in the macro definition. The semicolon becomes part of the expansion of the macro, so your statement

```
custom_text = DEFAULT_TEXT;
```

becomes

```
custom_text = "hello world";;
```

The extra semicolon doesn't happen to cause any problems in this case, but it could result in a syntax error or worse in other contexts. The expansion of your macro should be a valid expression. (Macros can expand to other things, but expressions are perhaps the most common case.)

Comment: *You could also define your function with a default parameter value rather than writing that logic in the body of the function.*  But if the caller can pass in a `nullptr` (as a literal like in the OP's code, or through a variable), then Bad Things happen.

Comment: There was still the problem with the dangling pointer, but Ben Voigt already answered it in a comment. It was not my construct. I only asked because I wasn't sure if I should fix it.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, so either the function should recognized a `nullptr` argument or the documentation should say it requires a non-null pointer. With a default argument, the call in the example would be `print_text();`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the function looks the following way

```
void print_text(const char* custom_text) {

    if(!custom_text) {
        custom_text = "hello world";
    }

    std::cout << custom_text << std::endl;
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the function.

String lietarls have static storage duration and types of constant character arrays

That is in memory the string literal `"hello world"` is stored similarly to the character array

```
static char hello_world[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', \0' };
```

Comment: "String literals have static storage duration" is true and important to OP, but I don't think he knows how that affects his code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest source of confusion is the parameter-type it self:

`void print_text(const char* custom_text)`

`const` is a bit special with to which thing it belongs:
This is a function called "print_text" that takes a pointer to a constant `char`. It is not the pointer that is constant but the value pointed too that is not allowed to be changed. (there is the whole east-const vs west-const).
So you are allowed to change were `custom_text` points to, as in changing it from pointing to a nullptr to point towards some string-literal, but you would not be allowed to change the content of what it is pointing at (and you can't change the content of string-literals to begin with).